# Custom properties in form control

Tags: orbeon, form-control, custom-properties

I'm currently using Orbeon v. 2017.1.1 embedded in an ASP .Net core web app written in C#. 
I need to add some custom properties to a form control. These properties are a key-value pair.
Is there some pre-built mechanism that let me add these properties,  or I have to implement such mechanism in java modifying the source code? (I'm not a Java programmer :-(  ).

Thank you

Ivan

Comment: Could you tell us more about what those key/value properties would be be for, maybe give an example of how they would be used, who sets then, reads them, etc?

Comment: I need to add these properties into the Control settings, adding them to the other standard properties in the Basic Settings tab.

Comment: The key value pairs are <string name, string value>. The user will fill these values during form building, and I must be able to read them from the xform definition.

Comment: Got it, thank you for the additional info; I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162761/5295) below.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [your own tab to the Control Settings dialog](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/extension-api.html#custom-control-settings-tab). There you have a lot freedom as to what the tab does. You can create any type of UI you want, and store information entered in that tab by form authors anywhere you'd like in the form definition.

Two typical places where to store information are the control currently being editing (if you only need it to be part of the form definition), and the element to which the control is bound (if you want the information to be part of the form data).